# Android acclerometer - measuring slow acceleration

Tags: android, accelerometer

I could be showing an ignorance of basic physics here but can the accelerometer be used to measure a very slow but constant linear acceleration? For example:

Me and the phone are inside a vehicle that is accelerating, I want to detect if the acceleration the phone is experiencing is greater than 10 m/s at any one moment and that the same level of acceleration (or greater) has been maintained for the last 10 seconds?

Is that possible?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but 10 m/s isn't an acceleration, it's a speed. If you mean 10 m/s2, then after 10 seconds you'll be going about 180 kph(from a dead stop). I'm not sure what your definition of "a very slow acceleration" is, but...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say a car goes from 0kmph to 100kmph in 10 seconds
100kmph = 27.8 mps

acceleration = dv / dt = 27.8 mps / 10 sec = 2.78 m/s2

So apart from the earth 10m/s2 gravity, the phone will detect 2.78 m/s2 perpendicular to it, overall about sqrt(10*10 + 2.78*2.78) = 10.38 m/s2

So instead of about 10m/s2, you will get 10.38m/s2.

The phone sensors are not that great, so you have to be in a really fast car to reliably detect it.